# Custom LinearLayout does not change orientation

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I created a custom LinearLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView\>
  <CustomTextView\>
<LinearLayout\>
```

and I'll bring the class back here:

```
class LinearInfoView constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayoutCompat(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, 0)

    private val binding: LayoutLinearInfoBinding =
        LayoutLinearInfoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

    val titleTextView: TextView
        get() = binding.title
    val valueTextView: ReadMoreTextView
        get() = binding.value

    var title: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            binding.title.text = value
        }

    var value: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            binding.value.text = value
        }
    

    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.LinearInfoView,
            0,
            0
        ).apply {
            try {
                title =
                    getString(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_title) ?: "Not specified"
                value =
                    getString(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_value) ?: "Not specified"
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go to use this View, if I set the vertical orientation does not work and remains horizontal orientation.

How can i set orientation in my Custom LinearLayout?

## EDIT

In the `attrs.xml` file where I declare the attributes of my view, I override the `android:orientation` attribute and then assign the value entered by the user to the root of my view like this:

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="LinearInfoView">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
        <attr name="value" format="string" />
        <attr name="hideIfValueEmpty" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="android:orientation"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

LinearViewInfo.kt

```
 init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.LinearInfoView,
            0,
            0
        ).apply {
            try {
                hideIfValueEmpty =                    getBoolean(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_hideIfValueEmpty, false)
                title =
                    getString(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_title) ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
                value =
                    getString(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_value) ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
                binding.root.orientation =
                    getInt(R.styleable.LinearInfoView_android_orientation, 0)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update answer w/ solution

Comment: You have a redundant `LinearLayout` in your setup. Your `LinearInfoView` is itself a `LinearLayout`, so you don't need another one nested inside of it, but the `<LinearLayout>` tag in the internal layout is causing just that. That's also why you have to set the orientation manually on that inner one; it's not affected by the attributes set on the `<LinearInfoView>` tag. If you replace the `<LinearLayout>` tags with `<merge>` tags, that will cause the `TextView` and `CustomTextView` to be added directly to your `LinearInfoView`, and its `android:orientation` will work as you were expecting.